# Putting a JS sourcemap in a password protected directory

Tags: build-process, gruntjs, minify, uglifyjs, source-maps

I've recently started using uglify-js to compress my JavaScript. Source maps are a nice feature for debugging but, for us, part of the benefit of compressing our JavaScript is the obfuscation.

Would putting the source map in a password protected directory prevent a passive observer from using it to re-beautify our JavaScript? Would his have any undesirable side-effects?

I'm not familiar with how and when browsers request this file. I don't want it to trigger password prompts and inconvenience users but I also don't want it to be publicly viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using Grunt you can set up different routines for dev to production; i.e. you may find Sass comments useful in dev but when you go to production you want all the comments stripped out. Same with sourcemaps. What I like to do is test with minified scripts to make sure everything works before the site goes live, so that my development environment is as close to the production environment as possible.

Ideally, you should have a local clone of your production site in which you can bugfix, enhance etc, rather than debugging a live site.

Yes it's possible someone can still take your JavaScript and beautify it again, but I think they would need the (uncompressed) source files, which you wouldn't store on your website in the first place; all they'd then be left with is beautified JS that had 1 character variable and function names, practically useless to anyone :-)

Comment: We often screen-share with users to debug system-specific problems so it is definitely a plus for us to have the uncompressed source files available (ideally with simple password protection as well) when on remote machines. Looking for some sort of access-control so we can get to it when we need to but it's at least behind some primitive protection for people outside our org.

Comment: I think basic auth probably isn't the way to go then, as putting it behind that would require a password prompt when the JavaScript requests that file (i.e. for all users). Might have to do some server side logic instead, i.e. if you log in as admin you get access to the uncompressed source, but again if you have a robust cross browser test suite (using something like Jasmine) I don't know why you would need to be able to debug your production code. Debug should be done on a local copy with your local test suite. :)

Comment: Oftentimes the issues we screen share for end up being caused by a conflict with a browser extension, browser setting, malware, or any number of things that are impossible to catch beforehand. On one of our other project we have a flag we can set to include unminified scripts serverside -- that works I guess :)